# Print pdf using usb printer

Tags: java, android, printing, usb

I have pdf file and I want to print it via usb printer but I did not find any thing helpful
I try this  [github rep](https://github.com/pradeepksingh/Android-USB-printer)and it doesn't help me do what I want
I also search on other stackoverflow questions and nothing.
Anything for doing that please.

Comment: What about this? [How to detect and print from the USB printer from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903724/how-to-detect-and-print-from-the-usb-printer-from-android)

Comment: I suggest you update your question. Write all the details and attempts, because you have much more information and experience than it seems.

Comment: @hu-zza doesn't help

Comment: @hu-zza I want somthing like this app on printing side:     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loyverse.sale
I don't  think there is something else to add it

Comment: @toufiks Oh, sorry, I mistook you with K J.

Answer (score 0):

I think supporting thermal printers would be nice for the first step. This library looks well elaborated: [Android library for ESC/POS Thermal Printer](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android)

In addition, there is an [article on medium.com](https://medium.com/@folahan/how-to-print-from-android-devices-using-thermal-bluetooth-printer-8dbc4750699d) about this library with a [sample project](https://github.com/sanxy/BluetoothPrinter).

Comment: Thank you for that,but I hop to read the question again

Comment: I want to print "pdf " via "usb printer "

Comment: @toufiks I was just trying to think in the minds of the customers of your app. If I were to use such an app, I would probably use a thermal printer. :-)